# PyQt mainapp and threads with ActiveW

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt4

I am newbie to Python and PyQt and I have a problem. I am building a GUI to control other windows software. The link is established via ActiveX as

```
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()    
    self.appl.mcad = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("MotorCAD.appautomation")
```

From my mainapp I first need to load the data and afterwards do some calculation.  I imagined that I can use one thread for load and one for calculate although this may be a totally missed concept.

I tried like this:

```
class LoadThread (QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, appl):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.appl = appl    # Appl is used as an argument to pass in the class MainApp.

    def run (self):
         self.appl.mcad.SetVisible(False)

class RunThread (QtCore.QThread):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.parent = parent    
    def run (self):
        self.parent.mcad.SetVisible(True)
```

Both are called from mainapp when clicking some buttons.

```
    self.LoadThread = LoadThread(self)            
    self.LoadThread.start()
```

If I use the link in the LoadThread, I can send and receive data via ActiveX, so this works. But I have a problem:

1. The activeX connection is opened in LoadThread. How to share it with mainapp and RunThread? Now I get error:

   ```
   File "<COMObject MotorCAD.appautomation>", line 2, in SetVisible
   pywintypes.com_error: (-2147220995, 'Object is not connected to server', None, None)
   ```
2. Is this at all a good way to do it? Do I even need two threads or should I define another method in first thread?